# Get unique records from a table + sum if the record is not distinct

Tags: php, sql

I have a table in mysql like below :

Table name : Emp

```
Emp Name | Time 
_______________
ABC      | 1
ABC      | 2
ABC      | 3
PQS      | 4
XYZ      | 5
```

I want the output as below

```
Emp Name | Time 
_______________
ABC      | 6
PQS      | 4
XYZ      | 5
```

As you can see only the unique Emp names are returned and the time is added for each instance of Emp name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rudimentary aggregate `SUM()` grouping by `Emp Name`:

```
SELECT 
  EmpName,
  SUM(Time) AS Time
FROM Emp
GROUP BY EmpName
ORDER BY EmpName
```

Review [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) on aggregate functions and the use of `GROUP BY` clauses.

Note, if your column name is actually `Emp Name` with the space, you will need to quote it with backticks as in:

```
SELECT 
  `Emp Name`,
  SUM(Time) AS Time
FROM Emp
GROUP BY `Emp Name`
ORDER BY `Emp Name`
```

Comment: Two notes: in the first query you're giving wrong aliases. In the second you're giving one wrong alias.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
SELECT
   EmpName,
   SUM(Time) AS Total
FROM
  table1
GROUP BY
   EmpName
```